# Tailwind CSS Laravel Mix Error - Forces PostCSS 8 to be installed

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, tailwind-css

I recently created a new laravel 8 project using Breeze for the authentication and tailwind css. All worked perfectly when running `npm run watch` but once I run `npm run prod` I ran into errors. I noticed that the Tailwind docs mention that there are PostCSS issues so you need to unistall and run

```
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

I done that however every time I run `npm run prod` now the build quits at 98% and says

```
Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.

Running: npm install postcss@^8.1 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
npm WARN browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.2.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1 || ^2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Finished. Please run Mix again.
```

This auto updates PostCSS to 8.1 every time.
After that if I run `npm run prod` again it does the exact same message over and over.

I've tried removing the browsersync plugins and trying again but it still doesn't work.

Anyone ran into this or got a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Digvijay mentioned above the new Mix v6 now supports PostCSS 8. So run:

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

After the when you run `npm run prod` you will still get this message:

```
Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.

Running: npm install browser-sync browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.2.2 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps

npm WARN browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.2.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1 || ^2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Finished. Please run Mix again.
```

To fix this just add sudo to the front of the npm command it ran:

```
sudo npm install browser-sync browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.2.2 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
```

Now run npm run prod and it should work!

Answer (score 3):

laravel-mix v6 now [supports PostCSS8](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/kgzgb8/laravel_mix_6_released_webpack_5_postcss_8_vue/)

According to [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel#setting-up-tailwind-css), it suggests to use `npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

With the new Mix v6, run `npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`

After this, `npm run prod` will run the way it should.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I never realised Post CSS worked with the new Mix version, cheers. I realised it kept installed browser-sync because I still had the brower sync code in my webpack file, I removed this and npm run prod now works but once I readded it I'm still getting the ""npm WARN browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.2.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1 || ^2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself."" error. So it's obviosuly a browser sync issue now.

Answer (score 2):

you must upgrade laravel mix using the following command

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

Comment: Fixed this pb in my case (Laravel 8)