# Laravel 8 Tailwind: webpack-cli TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

I want to install Tailwind in Laravel 8. I've followed the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel) and typed the following (showed no error).

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Then I could not successfully run `npm run watch` because there was a problem with installing the latest PostCSS version, v8. I've looked at a solution, and according to [Tailwind CSS Laravel Mix Error - Forces PostCSS 8 to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821093/tailwind-css-laravel-mix-error-forces-postcss-8-to-be-installed), I had to upgrade Webpack. Then I typed:

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

This includes the latest Webpack version, according to the docs https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade. (no error was shown)

If I type `npm run watch,` I have the following error; I don't understand it and didn't find anything in Google... I'm looking for some help:

> npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node
> but npm is using /snap/node/3292/bin/node itself. Use the
> `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node
> binary npm was executed with.
>
> > @ watch /home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso
> > npm run development -- --watch
>
> npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node
> but npm is using /snap/node/3292/bin/node itself. Use the
> `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node
> binary npm was executed with.
>
> > @ development /home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso
> > cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"
>
> **[webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function**
> at BrowserSyncPlugin.apply (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/browser-sync-webpack-plugin/lib/BrowserSyncPlugin.js:22:12)
> at createCompiler (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:74:12)
> at create (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:127:16)
> at webpack (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:135:47)
> at WebpackCLI.f [as webpack] (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:55:16)
> at WebpackCLI.createCompiler (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1845:29)
> at async WebpackCLI.buildCommand (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1952:20)
> at async Command. (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:742:25)
> at async Promise.all (index 1)
> at async Command. (/home/x/Documents/projets/web/site_perso/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1289:13)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! @ development:
> `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the @
> development script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
> There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/x/.npm/_logs/2021-06-06T08_40_27_985Z-debug.log npm ERR! code
> ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
> is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/x/.npm/_logs/2021-06-06T08_40_28_010Z-debug.log

Here is an extract of my `package.JSON` file, for dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "less-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved the issue by reinstalling `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` which, according to the error, is the plugin that causes the error. Here are the following commands that solved my problem:

```
npm uninstall browser-sync-webpack-plugin
npm install browser-sync-webpack-plugin
```

It upgraded this plugin's `package.JSON`'s line from "^2.0.1" to "^2.3.0".

I think I should update all my NPM plugins (see NPm commands `npm outdated` and `npm update`).

Comment: Or just run `npm install -D browser-sync-webpack-plugin@latest` to update